# How to count from down to up with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you see on my example I have `.minus` and `.plus` classes with my input text. So when I click plus I want to add number value to top if I click minus I want to add to down from zero (sorry my bad english)

I mean my minimum value must be:  `0` and my maximum value must be: `unlimited` or `50` or `500`

how can I do that ?

```css
.count-box {
  margin: 30px;
}

.count-box i {
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-box">
  <h3>ADULT</h3>
  <i class="plus">+</i>
  <input type="text" value="1">
  <i class="minus">-</i>
</div>


<div class="count-box">
  <h3>CHILDREN</h3>
  <i class="plus">+</i>
  <input type="text">
  <i class="minus">-</i>
</div>

<div class="count-box">
  <h3>BABY</h3>
  <i class="plus">+</i>
  <input type="text">
  <i class="minus">-</i>
</div>

<div class="total-box">
  <h1>TOTAL:</h1> <span class="total-count"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "my maximum value must be: unlimited or 50 or 500". Well which one is it? You can't have all 3 possibilities at once. And what have you tried so far? At least you must add event handlers to the plus/minus buttons. You can google how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: doesn't matter unlimited or 50 I just want to change from variable but let we say 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check updated snippet below..

```js
$(function(){
    updateTotal();
    $('.plus').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).siblings('input').val())+1);
        updateTotal();
    })
    
    $('.minus').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).siblings('input').val())-1);
        updateTotal();
    })


})
function updateTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input').each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    })
    $('.total-count').html(total);
}
```

```css
.count-box {
  margin: 30px;
}

.count-box i {
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-box">
  <h3>ADULT</h3>
  <i class="plus">+</i>
  <input type="text" value="1" min="0">
  <i class="minus">-</i>
</div>


<div class="count-box">
  <h3>CHILDREN</h3>
  <i class="plus">+</i>
  <input type="text" min="0" value="0">
  <i class="minus">-</i>
</div>

<div class="count-box">
  <h3>BABY</h3>
  <i class="plus">+</i>
  <input type="text" min="0" value="0">
  <i class="minus">-</i>
</div>

<div class="total-box">
  <h1>TOTAL:</h1> <span class="total-count"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: great thank you so what kind of statement should I set to limited to zero ? for example to not using -1,-3,-x

Comment: @ani_css instead of input type `text` you can use `number`. so it give automatically `+/-` buttons, also it accept `min/max` attribute for `value`.

Comment: I tried to use but it's not cross browser some customers are using ie9 and 10 thank you so much :)

Comment: then you can check all validations in `updateTotal()` function.

Comment: if($(this)<0){
return false; // I guess it has to work thanks
}

Comment: Ok I did it thanks a lot